# Scrapy: How do I crawl from a page and return to calling page correctly? "missing 1 required positional argument: 'response'. "

Tags: callback, scrapy, web-crawler

I am crawling a forum and extracting the user information data. Most of the data is on the user page but the list of followers and followees of the user require the spider to navigate into a link and return.

Below is my code that fetches the link:

`followers_link=response.xpath(".//div[contains(@class, 'section') and contains(.//span, 'Followers')]/h3/a/@href").extract_first()`

I, then have to call something like the below:

```
.......
f = response.follow(followers_link, self.parse_followers())
.......
yield items

def parse_followers(self, response):
   items=EcigUsers()
   followers = "-".join(response.xpath("//*[@class='username StatusTooltip']/text()").extract())
   items['followers']=followers
   return followers
```

I understand this is not correct but I am having trouble understanding how to fetch the followers list data and return back to the calling function. The response.follow line throws a
*missing 1 required positional argument: 'response'*

Any pointers will help! Thank you!

Comment: In the callback dont put parenthesis. It should be 
`response.follow(followers_link, self.parse_followers)`

Comment: Thank you @KishanMehta! That helped. But i think my logic is still flawed. I can't return 'followers' as it is a string. How do i yield followers? Can you help?